# How simplify my table when I'm creating it in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to simplify my code, like I have "Asics Gel 2000" two times, and when I'm creating my table I want to add it with a multiplicator *2 ! Look the example:

```
catalogue_tableau = ["Asics Gel 2000", "Asics Gel 2000", "Mizuno Wave rider", "Nike Air zoom", "Mizuno Wave plus", "Mizuno Wave plus", "Mizuno Wave plus", "Merrell Poseidon"]
```

And I would like to simplify like this:

```
catalogue_tableau = ["Asics Gel 2000"]*2, "Mizuno Wave rider", "Nike Air zoom", ["Mizuno Wave plus"] * 3,"Merrell Poseidon"]
```

But It's false and this isn't working. Somebody can help me ?

Answer (score 3):

You created a tuple with multiple strings and a few lists.

You can use the `*` *iterable unpacking* syntax inside a `[...]` list display, instead:

```
catalogue_tableau = [
    *(["Asics Gel 2000"] * 2),
    "Mizuno Wave rider", "Nike Air zoom",
    *(["Mizuno Wave plus"] * 3),
    "Merrell Poseidon"
]
```

The expression inside each `*(...)` group is expected to contain an iterable, whose values are added to the list in that location.

Comment: Thank you, that will help me a lot !

Answer (score 0):

you can do it as follows:

```
catalogue_tableau = ["Asics Gel 2000"]*2 + [ "Mizuno Wave rider", "Nike Air zoom"] + ["Mizuno Wave plus"] * 3 + ["Merrell Poseidon"]
```